# How is the data-bs-toggle supposed to work in bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
     
<button data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu">TOGGLE</button>

<div class="collapse" id="navmenu">
   <div>ONE</div>
   <div>TWO</div>
   <div>THREE</div>
</div>
```

Why does the `data-bs-toggle` work here for the `collapse` class, but it doesn't work if I instead have a different class name? If I change `collapse` to `asd` for instance, the toggle doesn't work. Why?

The toggle also works with the keyword `dropdown` but only when there's a container with the class name `dropdown-menu`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>


 <div>
        <button data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
          Dropdown link
        </button>
      
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div>ONE</div>
            <div>TWO</div>
            <div>THREE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't understand why? What is the logic here? I thought the `data-bs-target` specifies the element, and the `data-bs-toggle` specifies the class or id for toggling. Why does it only work for `collapse` and `dropdown` and weirdly enough the element is `dropdown-menu` not even `dropdown`.

Somebody please explain! I already read the documentation in bootstrap, but there is zero explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since **data-bs-toggle** expects the components inbuilts from Bootstrap and especifies what component wil toggle. `asd` is not a component such as `Dropdown` and `Collapse`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `data-bs-target` to the class you want! `data-bs-toggle` is an attribute for bootstrap functions!